# Persistência usando Fluent API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, fluent-api

Como faço para persistir um endereço sem ter que passar toda a informação do cliente?

Segue abaixo meu mapeamento de cliente endereco:

```
HasMany(f => f.EnderecoList)
            .WithMany(e => e.ClienteList)
            .Map(me =>
            {
                me.MapLeftKey("ClienteId");
                me.MapRightKey("EnderecoId");
                me.ToTable("EnderecosCliente");
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é você não usar a *Fluent API*, e sim uma entidade associativa:

```
public class Cliente
{
    /* Propriedades do Cliente */

    public virtual EnderecoCliente EnderecoCliente { get; set; }
}

public class Endereco
{
    /* Propriedades do Endereco */

    public virtual EnderecoCliente EnderecoCliente { get; set; }
}
```

E então:

```
public class EnderecoCliente 
{
    [Key]
    public int EnderecoClienteId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_EnderecoCliente_ClienteId_EnderecoId", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_EnderecoCliente_ClienteId_EnderecoId", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int EnderecoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

Definindo:

```
var endereco = new Endereco 
{
    /* Defina aqui outras propriedades */
    EnderecoCliente = new EnderecoCliente {
        Cliente = contexto.Clientes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClienteId == 5)
    }
};
```

[`[Index]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute(v=vs.113).aspx), introduzido nesta forma a partir do Entity Framework 6.1.0, garante a unicidade do registro associativo. Validações adicionais podem ser necessárias na aplicação para evitar erros estranhos de duplicidade de chave para o usuário.

Comment: como ficaria minha model no momento da persistência de um novo endereço , eu teria um list de EnderecoCliente, é isso ?

Comment: Uma lista não. Um único registro.

Comment: Coloquei errado o exemplo. Agora está certo.

Comment: mas a questão é a persistencia, suponha que no momento em que estou cadastrando endereços esse cliente possua 3 ou 4 endereços diferentes. Como persisto isso se o model só recebe um registro ?

Comment: Então, veja se agora ficou mais claro. Eu editei a resposta.

Comment: só pra entendimento eu tenho um cadastro que me diz o seguinte, endereço de cobrança, endereço de entrega, endereço residencial, cada um num lugar diferente , como persistir isso ? Obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Então, você cria usando aquela sintaxe que eu coloquei ali em cima. O bloco de criar a associação com o cliente é o mesmo para os 4.

Answer (score 1):

Do jeito que está mapeando é uma relação de muitos-para-muitos...  se você quiser que um cliente tenha vários endereços tente alguma coisa assim:

```
    public class ClienteEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual HashSet<EnderecoEntity> Enderecos { get; set; }
}

public class EnderecoEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }

    public int? CodigoCliente { get; set; }
    public virtual ClienteEntity Cliente { get; set; }
}

public class ClienteContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ClienteEntity> Clientes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EnderecoEntity> Enderecos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<ClienteEntity>()
            .HasMany(t=>t.Enderecos)
            .WithOptional(c=>c.Cliente)
            .HasForeignKey(c=>c.CodigoCliente);
    }
}
```

Com isso é possível preencher vários endereços com um cliente e chegar a partir do endereço no cliente correspondente...